# Creating foreign key in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to create 2 tables in Visual Studio server pane and I have a problem creating the foreign keys.

When I'm trying to create them in the relationship page it won't let me create foreign keys until I make them primary keys.

I don't understand why I can't have a different member in my table that it is primary key and a different one a foreign key.

My tables are like this:

**Table People:**

```
Primary key: ID int
             Name nvarchar
             Age int
             City nvarchar
Foreign key: AccountNumber int  --> when I make him primary key everything works.
```

**Table BankAccount:**

```
    
Primary key and Foreign Key: AccountNumber  int
                             Money float
```

ps.
I used some mysql with CMD and I remember that I could do this, but because I don't have this control in visual studio I'm lost.

UPDATE:
Rup made a good point that i only relize afther answering the qustion he ask me
i just did the realtionship (Foreign Key) for the bank account table and now i got
what i wanted thank you!

Comment: thank you :) i didnt know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not clear which way around the PKs and FKs are. BankAccount.AccountNumber should be a PK not an FK, and People.AccountNumber should be a FKR to BankAccount.AccountNumber. It ought not need to be a PK, in fact it shouldn't. Are you trying to FK the wrong way? And which database engine are you connecting to in Visual Studio? It'll almost certainly accept SQL if you'd rather do that.

Comment: im not sure about the engin im using but is the defult that come with visual studio.i dont understand how can i do a FK the worng way i just want to make sure that i have an ID as primery key and a forgien key as AccountNumber should i try to add reltionship from the bank account table?

Comment: It's probably SQL Server Compact or Express then. If it wants you to make People.AccountNumber the primary key then you're already trying to add the foreign key from the bank account table aren't you? You want to add it from the People table end.

Comment: yeah that what i did lol i relize it afther i answer you first qustion thank you for the fast reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is BankAccount.AccountNumber a Foreign Key?  Are you trying to reference back to the the person who owns it?

If that is the case, BankAccount should be:

```
CREATE TABLE BankAccount
(
   AccountNumber int PK,
   Money float,  // bad idea.  Use currency or int (i.e. store balance as pennies)
   Owner int FK REFERENCES People.ID
)
```

And drop the account ID from the people table.

This models the relationship  "an Account has 1 and only one owner" and allows the relationship "A person can have many accounts."

It looks like what you're trying to do is create a back reference.  If you were to choose to do this, then the back reference to the owner should be on People.ID, not on account. -- Although this is unnecessary because you can simply query

```
SELECT * FROM
BankAccount INNER JOIN People ON BankAccount.Owner = People.ID
```

to get all accounts and their owners.

If you want to establish multiple owners for an account, AND many accounts per user, then you need to establish a third table to implement the many-to-many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE AccountOwners
(
   AccOwnID int PK,
   AccountID int FK REFERENCES BankAccount.AccountNumber,
   PeopleID int FK REFERENCES People.ID
)
```

And drop the People.AccountNumber and BankAccount.Owner.  This technique is akin to maintaining a list of all accounts and owners which you can query.

Comment: wow thank you for that,this make a lot of things much clear to me!